# Oracle 10g: same query, different plans on copies of the same DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, execution-plan, explain

I have a query joining a number of long tables (primary key in one table, indexed column in another) which results in different plans on different copies of the same database.

The structure of copies including indices is the same and the data is 99+% the same (copies are made within a week from each other so some of them hold a bit more or fewer rows, the difference is totally insignificant for that particular query).

The problem is that on some copies Oracle applies the indices as expected while on another ones there is always a full table scan even if you specify a hint.

What factors can be influencing the plan apart from the data structure itself? For example, are there any dynamic ones such available RAM or anything like that? In other words, what should I check after I make sure that the DB structure of the "good" copy (which uses the indices) is identical to the "bad" one (which uses full scans)?

Or is it nonsense and different plans mean differences in data structure which I simply haven't noticed for some reason?

Comment: You've probably not gathered statistics on one of the databases

Comment: No, the stats are gathered for every table in the schema regularly.

Comment: Compare all your parameters (including any hidden parameter you might have touched), and compare the stats on the affected tables.

Comment: If you are using bind variables and histograms (enabled by default), I'd first of all blame bind peeking. Try disabling automatic histogram collection for the tables/columns involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other parameters that can influence execution plan, like PGA size, number of CPUs, disk I/O speed, different sample sizes when you are gathering statistics, index modifications, different system load, different block sizes and so on and on.

Just too many to check them all.

You could try sqlTXplain or sql Health Check Oracle's tools to find the root cause of this problem.

Run it for the same query on both databases and compare parameters that you will get(sqlTXplain compare method).